# como puedo imprimir un array en java?

Tags: java, array, switch

Soy principiante de java y estoy intentando hacer un torneo de 8 equipos de futbol, en los cuales los primeros 4 partidos los dicto yo, pero las semi finales y finales se ordenaran en base a los resultados de cada equipo ingresados por un usuario, mi idea era crear un array con condicionales if else, pero no funciono, luego intente con un switch y me imprime un resultado que no se como interpretar, dejo mi código abajo(tengan paciencia si hay errores lógicos muy brutos, soy principiante xD)

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Prueba_Switch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int P = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese los goles del equipo peniarol"));
        int C = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese los goles del equipo Cerro"));
        int G1 = 2;
        int[] SemiF= new int[4];    
        switch(G1) {
        case 1:
            if(P<C) {
                SemiF[0] = C;
            }else {
                SemiF[0]= P;
            }break;
        }
        System.out.println(SemiF);
    }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SemiF));`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [Arrays.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) que devuelve una representación de cadena del contenido del array especificado.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SemiF));
```

---

Recuerda que para que entre a la opción del Switch el valor de G1 debe ser 1:

```
        int P = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese los goles del equipo peniarol"));
        int C = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese los goles del equipo Cerro"));
        int G1 = 1; //2;
        int[] SemiF= new int[4];    
        switch(G1) {
        case 1:
            if(P<C) {
                SemiF[0] = C;
            }else {
                SemiF[0]= P;
            }break;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(SemiF));
```